# ¿Como creo un metodo que recorra un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Necesito hacer un método que verifique si el ID de la silla no ha sido ocupado anteriormente, la información de la sillas ocupadas se agrega con el metodo `crearSilla()` y estos valores quedan guardados en el ArrayList necesito verificar que no se haya puesto la ID de la silla anteriormente exactamente el ejercicio dice así:

Disponibilidad de sillas: este método recibe un parámetro el cual es un
entero que indica el número de silla a comprar. El método busca si el número de
silla ingresado está disponible y retorna verdadero si está disponible falso de lo
contrario.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sillas {
    
    private int numerosacumulables;
    private int id;
    private String tribuna;
    private int numero;
    private ArrayList<Sillas> numeros = new ArrayList<Sillas>();

    public Sillas(int id, String tribuna, int numero) {
        this.id = id;
        this.tribuna = tribuna;
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTribuna() {
        return tribuna;
    }

    public void setTribuna(String tribuna) {
        this.tribuna = tribuna;
    }

    public int getNumero() {
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(int numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    
    public void crearSilla(int id, String tribuna, int numero){
        Sillas silla = new Sillas(id, tribuna, numero);
        numeros.add(silla);
    }
    
    public void verSilla(){
        numerosacumulables = 0;
        numeros.forEach(Silla -> {
            System.out.println(Silla.getId());
            System.out.println(Silla.getTribuna());
            System.out.println(Silla.getNumero());
            numerosacumulables += 1;
        });
    }
    
    public void disponibleSilla(){
    }
    
}


package Ejercicio12;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Sillas silla1 = new Sillas(0, "", 0);
        Sillas silla2 = new Sillas(0, "", 0);
        silla1.crearSilla(8, "Sur", 120);
        silla1.crearSilla(5, "Norte", 60);
        
        silla1.verSilla();
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: realiza un bucle for el cual compare el parametro dado con el getId() de cada objeto guardado en el ArrayList ,devulve true si hay considencia

Comment: mmmm... supongo que estas haciendo programación orientada a objetos, te recomiendo que la estructura de las clases, si es que esas clases las has creado tú... la cambies, porque creo que te estas haciendo un lío sólo con tu estructura, yo que tengo mucha experiencia con java me ha costado pillarla. ¿Una silla que tiene dentro un array de Sillas que se llama números? ¿Una silla tiene sillas dentro de ella? o, mas bien, ¿una clase AlmacenSillas tiene Sillas dentro? Programación orientada a objetos, hay que intentar seguir una lógica para que todo sea más legible

Answer (score 0):

```
public Boolean disponibleSilla(int numSilla){
        // iterador      ArrayList<Sillas>
    for (Sillas sillas : this.numeros) {
        //si sillas.id = numSilla : return true;
        if (sillas.id == numSilla)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: ¿qué hace tu código? si llega una persona que tenga el mismo problema, no va a saber qué hace que cosa, si pudieras explicar estaría súper :D